# php directory reading issue

Tags: php, directory, traversal

I have written this simple script display all the files in a directory as a set of buttons.

This code reads from the upload directory and displays all files inside a submit button in a form.

```
$handle = opendir("upload");
echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="download.php">';
while($name = readdir($handle)) {
  echo '<input type="submit" name="file" value='.$name.' />';
}
echo '</form>';
```

Now the issue here is; every time I run the script I find two button at the beginning with contents `.` and `..`

I have not been able to figure out what causes this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have encountered are two special files used by the file system.

- `.` represents the current directory you are in.<sup>1</sup>
- `..` represents the parent directory of the current directory.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>**Footnotes:**</sup>
    <sup><sup>1.</sup>  A path such as *"/my_dir/././././././file"* is equivalent to *"/my_dir/file"*.</sup>
    <sup><sup>2.</sup> A path such as *"/my_dir/../my_dir/../my_dir/file"* is equivalent to *"/my_dir/file"* since `..` will make you move "up" one level.</sup>

---

To get around the issue of showing these two to your user filter the content returned by `readdir` using something as the below:

```
while  ($name = readdir ($handle)) {
  if ($name == '.' || $name == '..')
    continue; /* don't echo anything, skip to next read */

   echo '<input type="submit" name="file" value='.$name.' />';
}
```

Comment: aah i had thought of using if block to skip them, just wanted to know what they meant! and thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

the directory listing includes . for the current dir and .. for the parent dir.

I usually use this that i got from the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

so what you need to do is to exclude the . and .. from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a FilesystemIterator like this:

```
foreach(new FilesystemIterator('upload') as $file){
    echo $file;
}
```

It will automatically skip . and .. entries in the filesystem.